# How to continue a resize of div(s) horizontally, when browser width is lessened

Tags: css, angularjs

OK, this is probably very simple, but with the hacks we have in our code, it's not clear.

Step 1 - I have a DIV that contains a Google Map. What's IN the div is unimportant.

Step 2 - The size of the div is determined by the following Angular call:

```
data-ng-style="{ width: gmMapWidth }
```

Here's the Angular call that sets this attribute:

$scope.gmMapWidth = '100%';

As I scrunch the browser: sideways, the div, see below:

```
<div id="profile-map" data-ng-show="mapLoaded && showDemoMap" data-ng-style="{ width: gmMapWidth }" data-ng-class="{'show': gmMapWidth != 0 }" style="background: url(/app/css/images/demo/fake-map.png) no-repeat left top;"></div>
```

So when I reach a limit of Width: 591px in the Browser (GOOGLE CHROME) debugging console, the div stops and no longer shrinks although there's plenty more room for it to shrink (width-wise).

Any thoughts on how to get this to "be more responsive?"

Comment: Silly question but do you have a min-width specified anyway which targets a div? Anything general on a div could be stopping you.

Comment: My friend, no question is silly. So when I check the browser after load here's what I see:  style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px); width: 100%; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);"  This is added AFTER the angular stuff propagates. Now I'll check the CSS and get back to you.  Stand by

Comment: If you can drop as much of your markup in jsFiddle as you can that would most helpful.

Comment: Well, this question is now moot. The project was summarily cancelled and my contract ended. I'm sorry.